# Is setRequestHeader mandatory in Javascript for the POST method

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is it mandatory to use `setRequestHeader` while sending data using post method? If yes, what does it contain and can we use `object` or `Array` to send a data to server. I used GET and POST methods many times but did not use `setRequestHeader` in JQuery.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax_test.asp", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default content type. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using `setRequestHeader` is not mandatory. Only use it if you need it.

No, you cannot pass an array or object to setRequestHeader directly. You can however use a utility method to do this. For example

```js
function setRequestHeaders(xhr, headers) {
  for (var headerName in headers) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(headerName, headers[headerName]);
  }
}

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
setRequestHeaders(xmlhttp, {
  "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "foobar": "bazbat",
  ...
});
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: When we need setRequestHeader